# small caps roman numbers for index entries with xindy and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, indexing, xindy

Considering the following example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
%\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}%doesn't help
\usepackage{hyperref} %commenting out this one would do.
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Something\index{Something}. And something else\index{Something else}
\mainmatter
Something\index{Something}. And something else\index{Something else}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

And the following minimal xindy style file, formatting roman page numbers as small caps:

```
(markup-locref :class "roman-page-numbers" :open  "\textsc{" :close "}")

$ xindy -M texindy -M scpages.xdy example.idx
```

This works when I comment out `hyperref`:

[image: working minimum example]

However with hyperref roman numbers do not get formatted as small caps:

[image]

How do I make it work with `hyperref`?

Edit: One possible workaround is to comment out `hyperref` just for building the index. Once I'm satisfied with the index I can comment it back in again, but I'll have to comment out `\makeindex` and *not* run xindy, which means that if because of editing my project some entries get pushed onto another page it will not automatically be reflected in the index. Also, in the pdf the page numbers will not be clickable. For print this workaround is sufficient, and at least `hyperref` works for the rest of the file, i.e. separate page ranges for front- and mainmatter in the pdf.

Edit:

Another temporary fix is to run a perl one liner over the `.ind`-file:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\\hyperpage{.*?})/\\textsc{$1}/g' myfile.ind
```

which encapsulates every instance of `\hyperpage{[some number]}` with `\textsc{}`. That way one doesn't need to switch `hyperref` between commented in and out, thus streamlining the build process. The numbers become clickable, and one gets the desired small caps for the roman numbers. This line can be conveniently added to a buildscript after the `xindy` call.

Comment: Just make the change to the format for all entries. `\textsc{\thepage}` is equivalent to `\thepage` if `\thepage` gives an Arabic numeral anyway. At least, normally it is. If you are using a particular font configuration it might not be. But it would be better to have the page numbering set up so `\thepage` does the right thing on its own.

Comment: I have in my archives the defifinition of a `\pagenumbering{scroman}`. Do you think it might be useful, and compatible with `memoir`?

Comment: @Bernard It might be useful. Just post it, I will see if it works, or if it can easily be adapted. My page headers I can easily change to work with that.

Comment: @Bernard I can more-or-less see how to do this for standard classes (just been looking before I saw your comment). But `memoir` seems to do something different and I can't figure it out at all.

Comment: @Bernard I am getting the impression that if I completely change the frontmatter page numbering to small caps I will have to define a new alphabet and a new location-class for `xindy`, not sure how trivial that would be.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a possible tool to achieve what you want. This defines 3 new page numbering styles. They were not written by me, but I can't remember who did, probably at my request, to solve some problem of old-style typography.

The 3 styles are: `scroman` (roman style with small caps), `osroman` (like roman, except if page number in consecutive `i`s, the last i is replaced with `j`, and `scosroman` (same as previous, with small caps). Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{lipsum}% texte bidon

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oldstyleroman}[1]{\expandafter\@oldstyleroman#1\@nil}
\def\@oldstyleroman#1#2\@nil{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\if#1ij\else#1\fi}% si #2 est vide
  {#1\@oldstyleroman#2\@nil}% si #2 n'est pas vide
}
\def\scroman#1{\expandafter\@scroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@scroman#1{{\scshape\romannumeral #1}}
\def\osroman#1{\expandafter\@osroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@osroman#1{{\oldstyleroman{\romannumeral #1}}}
\def\scosroman#1{\expandafter\@scosroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@scosroman#1{{\scshape\oldstyleroman{\romannumeral #1}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{scroman}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Titre}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Titre}
\label{page}
\lipsum[11-20]

\mainmatter
\chapter{A Matter of Styles}
\lipsum[21-25]

Voir page~\pageref{page}.


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question was about the index

Comment: @egreg: I know, that's why I only proposed this code as a *possible* tool to achieve what the O.P. wants

Comment: By now I sort of got it to work using a `xindy` style file, except I have to get it to play nice with `hyperref,` still thanks.

Comment: Oh, and your solution for changing the page numbers to small caps did also work after changing the class to `memoir`.