# Small caps/small letters for TOC page numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle

I use both Arabic (1, 2, ...) and Roman page numbering (I, II, ...) in my document. However the normal Roman figures look too dominant in the table of contents (e.g. XXVIII). The lower-case Roman numbers don't look good to me either (xxviii).

I would like to achieve the following:

- The Roman page numbering at the bottom of each page should be of standard-size capital letters.
- The Arabic page numbering at the bottom of each page should be of standard-sized numbers.
- The Roman page numbering in the table of contents should be of either standard-size small caps or of smaller capital letters. (They should not run as wide as regularly)
- The Arabic page numbering in the table of contents should be of standard-sized numbers.

The following is a MWE which shows what I have now.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{27}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{Section}
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \section{Section}
\end{document}
```

As you see, I use KOMA-Script. I'm open to using features from `tocstyle`, since I already use this package (see [KOMA-Script: Wrong alignment of roman numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290384/koma-script-wrong-alignment-of-roman-numbers)).

---

**NB:** This question at first asked by mistake for a solution using `tocloft`. This is why there are some answers using that.

Comment: You can use a `scroman` page numbering, defined in an answer I proposed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270049/small-caps-roman-numbers-for-index-entries-with-xindy-and-hyperref/270057#270057).

Comment: Do you really use `tocloft`? Or `tocstyle`? Note that the usage of `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.

Comment: @esdd Oops... I read multiple times and read it always wrong... Should I keep this question as is and ask a new one for `tocstyle` since there are already some answers for `tocloft` or just change it here? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the **upcoming KOMA-Script version 3.20** `tocstyle` will not be needed. There is already a [pre-release](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801) on the KOMA-Script website.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2016/10/23]
\newcommand\pagenumbertocfont[1]{\ifisinteger{#1}{#1}{\tiny #1}}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocdynnumwidth,
    tocpagenumberbox=\hbox,
    tocpagenumberformat=\pagenumbertocfont
]{part,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocpagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\pagenumbertocfont
]{part,section}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{27}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \part{Part}
    \blinddocument

    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

With the **current version 3.19a** you can use `pagenumberhook` from package `tocstyle`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocfeature{pagenumberbox}{\hbox}

\newcommand\pagenumbertocfont[1]{\ifisinteger{#1}{#1}{\tiny #1}}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\pagenumbertocfont}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberhook}{\pagenumbertocfont}
\settocstylefeature[1]{pagenumberhook}{\pagenumbertocfont}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{27}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \part{Part}
    \blinddocument

    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

---

This works also with the standard class `article`. But then you have to load package `scrextend` additionally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocfeature{pagenumberbox}{\hbox}

\newcommand\pagenumbertocfont[1]{\ifisinteger{#1}{#1}{\tiny #1}}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\pagenumbertocfont}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberhook}{\pagenumbertocfont}
\settocstylefeature[1]{pagenumberhook}{\pagenumbertocfont}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{27}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \part{Part}
    \blinddocument

    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest thing to do is use the `tocloft` package to set the appearance of the toc.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\bfseries\small\sffamily}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \setcounter{page}{27}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{Section}
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \section{Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, this is without the `tocloft` settings:

[image]

Comment: @Mico The OP asked to use "small caps **or** smaller letters" for the numbering.  Since there is no bold small caps for that font, I opted for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've set the `tocloft` tag, I assume you're interested in using the package to modify the appearance of the Table of Contents. The following code shows how this might be done. Note the use of `\cftsetrmarg` and `\cftsetpnumwidth` to increase the amount of space that's set aside for page numbers -- roman numerals tend to take up a lot more space than arabic numerals do.

The Computer Modern font family doesn't provide a sans-serif/small-caps/bold combination of font attributes. The code below therefore generates serif/non-bold small-cap page numbers in the ToC.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetrmarg{4em} % set aside more space for roman numerals
\cftsetpnumwidth{3.5em}  
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\scshape}

\begin{document}
    %%\pagenumbering{roman} 
    \renewcommand\thepage{\scshape\roman{page}} % <- new
    \setcounter{page}{37}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \subsubsection{A very very very very very  very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long subsubsection header}
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \section{Section}
\end{document}
```